# custom fault message in IBM webspher esb

Tags: java, esb, websphere-esb

I have a WS that copy’s the data to an Oracle server. Now I need to find the proper syntax in Java in order to use the custom mediation that will show me in the fault message the specific error of why it didn't succeed. Right now all I’m getting is: internal error or something like this.

Does anyone here know how to assist me?

Comment: I just need more information on the error...

Comment: it's not a log thing, I need to construct is in the custom mediation componet